# Javascript autofill text fields

Tags: javascript

How do I autofill two fields with JavaScript code?

Field 1 should be written *"Paragraph"*.

Field 2 should be written *"Source"*.

Field 1 HTML:

```html
<h1 dir="auto" data-placeholder="Title" data-label="Title" class="empty">
  <br>
</h1>
```

Field 2 HTML:

```html
<p dir="auto" data-placeholder="Name story..." class="empty">
  <br>
</p>
```

Comment: So where did you get stuck, in what way, when you tried to solve this yourself? Can you share those problems, and your attempted code?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
[["h1","Paragraph"],["p","Source"]].forEach(([sel,txt])=>
 document.querySelector(sel).textContent=txt);
```

```html
<h1 dir="auto" data-placeholder="Title" data-label="Title" class="empty"><br></h1>
<p dir="auto" data-placeholder="Name story..." class="empty"><br></p>
```

Comment: It is changing Field 2 but doesnt change Field 1